# jQuery based push out and reveal image description between images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a text based description reveal with jQuery. I have a line of images and I would like when you click on an image that they push apart and the description gets revealed.
I have managed to do this to a point in the fiddle below, but the image does not push out it snaps out then the text animates across. I was hoping it would look more like it is pushing the image across and the text is coming out smoother.

```
$( ".img img" ).on( "click", function() {
    $('.desc').css('display','none');
    var bio_box = $(this).parent(".img").next(".desc");
    $(bio_box).toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
    }, 2000);
});
```

```js
$(".img img").on("click", function() {
  var bio_box = $(this).parent(".img").next(".desc");
  console.log(bio_box);
  $(bio_box).toggle('slide', {
    direction: 'right'
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

.img {
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.desc {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x400">
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    Desc 1 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet felis viverra urna sollicitudin lobortis at varius eros. Quisque sit amet sollicitudin nulla. Ut aliquet interdum neque id vehicula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis
    parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus aliquam, est sit amet vehicula tristique, erat magna placerat felis, vel maximus neque lacus at magna.
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x400">
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    Desc 2 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet felis viverra urna sollicitudin lobortis at varius eros. Quisque sit amet sollicitudin nulla. Ut aliquet interdum neque id vehicula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis
    parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus aliquam, est sit amet vehicula tristique, erat magna placerat felis, vel maximus neque lacus at magna.
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x400">
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    Desc 3 ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet felis viverra urna sollicitudin lobortis at varius eros. Quisque sit amet sollicitudin nulla. Ut aliquet interdum neque id vehicula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis
    parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus aliquam, est sit amet vehicula tristique, erat magna placerat felis, vel maximus neque lacus at magna.
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally if you click the second image, that images pushes out to the left and reveals the text smoothly. (Not snaps over and then the text slides out so there is a gap while the transition completes)